# Take pictures with camera and store in internal instead of external storage

Tags: java, android, android-studio, photo-gallery

I'm trying to take a picture with the built in Android camera. I've been following a tutorial that taught how to capture images, however it only teaches how to capture pictures and store them onto an SD card. At the moment the app crashes whenever trying to use the code for internal storage. Below is a portion of the code that I have that I'm not sure how to change in order to get things working for internal storage.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    _image = ( ImageView ) findViewById( R.id.image );
    _field = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.field );
    _button = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.button );
    _button.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler() );

     _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images/make_machine_example.jpg";
}
protected void startCameraActivity()
{
    File file = new File( _path );
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

    startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
}
```

Comment: Your code should work if the 'images' directory exists in that external storage location. But then it could crash in onActivityResult. Does it? You are not showing your code for that. And you should post the logcat because there you see the exception/error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your app tires to store in external storage (getExternalStorageDirectory()) which is mostly not the removable micro SD card. Besides removable and external memory android devices have internal memory too. To let the camara app drop a picture to your private internal storage you can provide a contentprovider.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot give a third-party app a path to your app's internal storage and expect the other app to be able to use it, as the other app has no read or write permissions to work with your internal storage.

The easy solution is to use external storage for the picture, then copy it to your desired spot on internal storage, deleting the original on external storage when the copy is done.

The perhaps-it-might-work solution would be to use a secured `FileProvider` to serve access to your internal storage to the camera app. This definitely works for allowing other apps to read your internal storage, and `FileProvider` appears to have support for write operations, though I have never tried it for write operations, let alone with a camera app.

The it'll-work-but-oy-it-is-a-lot-of-work solution is to take the picture yourself, using `android.hardware.Camera` and/or `android.hardware.camera2`, instead of invoking a third-party app.

Comment: why do you say the FileProvider option is the "perhaps-it-might-work solution"? What are your reservations against using it?

Comment: @marienke: Some camera apps will not support `Uri` values with a `content` scheme, like you get from `FileProvider`. For example, up until a year ago, Google's own Camera app did not support them. The problem as a developer is that you have no way to know whether a given `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity supports `content` or not.